# Webpage flickering while scrolling on IE 10 on windows phone 8

Tags: jquery, css, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a mobile website and facing this weird flickering/shaking while scrolling my web page in IE10 on my windows phone 8. I have used the following css for my container that contains my web page:

> ```
> position:fixed;
> top:0;
> left:0;
> overflow-y:scroll;
> -ms-scroll-snap-type: proximity;
> -ms-scroll-snap-points-y: snapInterval(0%, 100%);
> -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
> -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
> -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
> -ms-user-select: none;
> z-index:0;
> ```

please suggest any other approach.

**Update:**

The same is observed in Windows phone 8.1 with IE11

**Update 2:**

HTML:

```
<body onunload="">
    <div class="popupBox">
        <div class="popupContent">
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
        <div class="buttonContainer">
            <a class="closePopup" id="btnClosePopup" href="#">Ok</a> <a class="closePopup margLeft02"
                id="btnCancelConfirmBox" style="display: none;">Cancel</a>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="header">
            <a href="#" class="vault_navOpener">
                <img src="menu_button.png" alt=""></a>
            <div class="width87">
                <h1 class="logo">
                    <a href="#samplelink" id="IdHome">
                        <img src="logo.jpg" alt=""></a>
                </h1>
                <div class="vip_half">
                    <span class="vip_level">
                        <label id="lblVIPLevel">
                            4</label>
                    </span><span id="firstName">Hello Nishaa</span>
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                    <a id="NotTo" class="npd_logout">Log Out</a>
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>
                SweepLand<sup>®</sup></h2>
            <div class="main">
                <ul class="points">
                    <li><span class="width70"><span id="a">Points Available:</span></span> <span id="b"
                        class="width30">421</span>
                        <div class="clear">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="width70"><span id="c">SweepLand Points in Play:</span></span> <span
                        id="c1" class="width30">4</span>
                        <div class="clear">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="width70"><span id="d">BidLand Points in Play:</span></span> <span
                        id="d1" class="width30">163</span>
                        <div class="clear">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="width70"><span id="e">Total Points:</span></span> <span id="f" class="width30">
                        588</span>
                        <div class="clear">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clear bdr">
                </div>
                <h3>
                    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblFeaturedPrizes">Featured Prizes</span>
                </h3>
                <div class="featured">
                    <ul class="prizes" id="featured_prizes">
                        <li><a href="#samplelink">
                            <img src="6883.jpg" alt="" onerror="ShowImage(this);">
                        </a>
                            <h4>
                                <a href="#samplelink" class="blue">TestFeaturedSweep_25062014</a>
                            </h4>
                            <span class="width60 clear">5 Prizes</span> <span class="width60">Enter By:</span>
                            <span class="width40">28/08/14</span> <span class="width60 s_points">Points Entered:</span>
                            <span class="width40 s_points_value">
                                <input id="hdnMinFPoints0" value="0" type="hidden">
                                <label id="lblFPoints0">
                                    2</label>
                                <input id="txtFPoints0" value="2" type="text"></span>
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <a class="button_bid" id="btnFEdit0">Edit Points</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#samplelink">
                            <img src="6883.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                            <h4>
                                <a href="#samplelink" class="blue">TestFeaturedSweep_25062014</a>
                            </h4>
                            <span class="width60 clear">5 Prizes</span> <span class="width60">Enter By:</span>
                            <span class="width40">28/08/14</span> <span class="width60 s_points">Points Entered:</span>
                            <span class="width40 s_points_value">
                                <input id="Hidden1" value="0" type="hidden">
                                <label id="Label1">
                                    2</label>
                                <input id="Text1" value="2" type="text"></span>
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <a class="button_bid" id="A1">Edit Points</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#samplelink">
                            <img src="6883.jpg" alt="" onerror="ShowImage(this);">
                        </a>
                            <h4>
                                <a href="#samplelink" class="blue">TestFeaturedSweep_25062014</a>
                            </h4>
                            <span class="width60 clear">5 Prizes</span> <span class="width60">Enter By:</span>
                            <span class="width40">28/08/14</span> <span class="width60 s_points">Points Entered:</span>
                            <span class="width40 s_points_value">
                                <input id="Hidden2" value="0" type="hidden">
                                <label id="Label2">
                                    2</label>
                                <input id="Text2" value="2" type="text"></span>
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <a class="button_bid" id="A2">Edit Points</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear bdr">
                </div>
                <div class="clear">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content_footer">
            <div class="footer">
                <p class="copyright">
                    ©2014
                </p>
                <!-- Footer links here -->
                <ul style="width: 257px;" class="footerList">
                    <li><a href="#sampleLink" id="m"><span id="m1">About Us</span> </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#sampleLink" id="n"><span id="n1">Join</span> </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#sampleLink" id="o"><span id="o1">Privacy Policy</span></a></li>
                    <li class="noBdr"><a href="#sampleLink" id="p"><span id="p1">Terms of Use</span> </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="clear noBdr"></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clear margBt01">
                </div>
                <ul style="width: 203px;" class="footerList">
                    <li><a href="#sampleLink" id="q"><span id="q1">Security</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#sampleLink" id="r"><span id="r1">Unsubscribe</span></a></li>
                    <li class="noBdr"><a href="#sampleLink" id="s"><span id="s1">Contact Us</span></a></li>
                    <li class="clear noBdr"></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clear margBt01">
                </div>
                <!-- Footer icons here -->
                <a href="#sampleLink" id="t">
                    <img class="left" src="group-logo.png" alt=""></a> <a href="#sampleLink" id="trust">
                        <img class="right" src="mPrizeBoard.aspx_files/truste-logo-new.png" alt=""></a>
                <div class="clear">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS of .body div containing the page is below:

```
.body
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    z-index:0;

    -webkit-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.body > *
{
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

**Note:** *This is to specify that .body div gets its height and width dynamically which is always equal to the height and width of the window.*

Comment: You probably want to show some of your other html too. I tried the same css (without `position:fixed`) and it seemed working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that it flickers in quite the way it does, but this effect is probably created by the use of position:fixed.  This would make since as fixed tells the element to stay in position relative to the browser, so it can be used to create static navigation bars and so on.  With out seeing your HTML, it is hard to say exactly why this happens, but it is probably down to the browser having issues rendering an element that is fixed to the screen.

I have managed to replicate your issue, but could find no alternative to using position fixed.

Look at it this way, when you scroll, you are telling the page to move up or down, but using position:fixed is counteracting this can causing conflict.  As far as I know, all browsers will experience a small flicker when scrolling with the CSS you used, but it is too slight to notice, and this is amplified by the slow GPU in your phone, and the conflict you created.

Hope this helps :)

EDIT: I found another solution that could work, try adding overflow:auto to the element that this CSS affects.  I can’t tell you if this will work as you have not included and HTML, but its worth a try.  (This was found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166816/firefox-3-5-fixed-position-scrolling-annoying-flicker which is not the same, but a simmilar problem)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Sam. I have added the HTML to my question. Changing the position to absolute didn't work for me.

Comment: fair enough, it was unlikely, but thought i would suggest given the lack of responce so far

Comment: I accept that. But now if you have any solutions please let me know.